# SwiftUI Filtering a List

Tags: swift, list, filter, swiftui

Basically I have a decodable struct called `Treatment` that has two parameters: title and category. I'd like to create a list where `categoryName = treatment.category`. That way, only some of the treatments will be part of the List.

```
struct HomeSecondLevel: View { 
   let categoryName: String
   @ObservedObject var treatmentsManager = TreatmentsManager()
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List(treatmentsManager.treatments) { treatment in
                 Text(treatment.title)
         }}}}
```

I tried adding an 'if statement' (`if categoryName = treatment.category`) right below the List View, as an attempt to filter the list but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by passing **filtered** data to the `List`, copmuted in `filteredTreatments`.

In your question, `if categoryName = treatment.category` didn't work because you wrote `=` instead of `==`. That would work if fixed, but it shows empty spaces/rows where the `Treatment` doesn't match the category. To avoid the spaces, that's why the data here is filtered first.

Here is an example which will work for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HomeSecondLevel(categoryName: "e")
    }
}


struct HomeSecondLevel: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var treatmentsManager = TreatmentsManager()
    let categoryName: String
    var filteredTreatments: [Treatment] {
        treatmentsManager.treatments.filter { $0.category == categoryName }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(filteredTreatments) { treatment in
                Text(treatment.title)
            }
        }
    }
}


class TreatmentsManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var treatments: [Treatment] = [
        Treatment(title: "1", category: "o"),
        Treatment(title: "2", category: "e"),
        Treatment(title: "3", category: "o"),
        Treatment(title: "4", category: "e"),
        Treatment(title: "5", category: "o"),
        Treatment(title: "6", category: "e"),
    ]
}


struct Treatment: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let category: String
}
```